# Coreapi field showing wrong name(data) in swagger

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-swagger

I'm implementing the schema fields by using the method get_schema_fields in DRF. On the swagger UI for the form field instead of the name which ["**metrics**"] I have given it is displaying the **data** as the name. Also the model example is also not coming.

This is the code

```
def get_schema_fields(self, view):
        return [
            coreapi.Field(
                name='metrics',
                location='form',
                required=True,
                schema=coreschema.Object(),
                description='metrics type',
            ),
```

[image]

How can rename that field name from **data** to **metrics** also how to display the model sample?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to change **data** to **metrics**, all I know is you can add or remove fields in the "Example Value" or "Model" using `get_manual_fields` or `get_serializer_fields`, here there is an example:

```
def get_serializer_fields(self, path, method):
  fields = []
  if path == 'my_path' and method == 'PUT':
     fields = [coreapi.Field(
     "custom_field",
     required=True,
     location="",
     schema=coreschema.String()
     )]
   return fields
```

Here more documentation:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#get_serializer_fieldsself-path-method